# Slicing Pandas DataFrame based on csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a Pandas DataFrame like following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A','B','C'],
                'Country'  : ['US','UK','SL']})

  Country Name
0      US    A
1      UK    B
2      SL    C
```

And I'm having a csv like following.

```
Name,Extended
A,Jorge
B,Alex
E,Mark
F,Bindu
```

I need to check whether `df['Name']` is in csv and if so get the "Extended". **If not I need to just get the "Name"**. So my Expected output is like following.

```
 Country  Name  Extended
0      US    A  Jorge
1      UK    B  Alex
2      SL    C  C
```

Following shows what I tried so far.

```
f = open('mycsv.csv','r')
lines = f.readlines()

def parse(x):
    for line in lines:
        if x in line.split(',')[0]:
            return line.strip().split(',')[1]

df['Extended'] = df['Name'].apply(parse)

 Name Country Extended
0  A  US Jorge
1  B  UK Alex
2  C  SL None
```

I can not figure out how to get the "Name" for C at "Extended"(`else` part in the code)? Any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "fillna" function from pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A','B','C'],
            'Country'  : ['US','UK','SL']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('mycsv.csv', index_col=None)

df_merge = pd.merge(df, f, how="left", on="Name")
df_merge["Extended"].fillna('Name', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just load the csv as a df and then assign using `where`:

```
df['Name'] = df2['Extended'].where(df2['Name'] != df2['Extended'], df2['Name'])
```

So here we use the boolean condition to test if 'Name' is not equal to 'Extended' and use that value, otherwise just use 'Name'.

Also is 'Extended' always either different or same as 'Name'? If so why not just assign the value of extended to the dataframe:

```
df['Name'] = df2['Extended']
```

This would be a lot simpler.